# Angular ngFor index serial number

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a list of items that contains country and city names like following and I want to show the serial number for a specific type of item in list.

```
items = [
    {'type': 'Country', 'title': 'Armenia',  },
    {'type': 'City', 'title': 'Kapan'   },
    {'type': 'City', 'title': 'Goris'   },
    {'type': 'City', 'title': 'Hats’avan' },

    
    {'type': 'Country', 'title': 'Angola'  },
    {'type': 'City', 'title': 'Catabola'  },
    {'type': 'City', 'title': 'Camacupa' },
    {'type': 'City', 'title': 'Caluquembe'  },

    {'type': 'Country', 'title': 'Argentina'  },
    {'type': 'City', 'title': 'San Vicente'  },
    {'type': 'City', 'title': 'Santa Elena'  },
    {'type': 'City', 'title': 'Retiro'  },
  ];


<div>
    <p *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index;">
        <b>{{i+1}}.</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.title}} &nbsp; ({{item.type}})
    </p>
</div>
```

it is showing like this:

```
1.  Armenia   (Country)

2.  Kapan   (City)

3.  Goris   (City)

4.  Hats’avan   (City)

5.  Angola   (Country)

6.  Catabola   (City)

7.  Camacupa   (City)

8.  Caluquembe   (City)

9.  Argentina   (Country)

10.  San Vicente   (City)

11.  Santa Elena   (City)

12.  Retiro   (City)
```

But I want to display like this: ( Serial number should display only with city name )

```
    Armenia   (Country)

1.  Kapan   (City)

2.  Goris   (City)

3.  Hats’avan   (City)

    Angola   (Country)

4.  Catabola   (City)

5.  Camacupa   (City)

6.  Caluquembe   (City)

    Argentina   (Country)

7.  San Vicente   (City)

8.  Santa Elena   (City)

9.  Retiro   (City)
```

Here is the stackblitz where I tried

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-serial-number-dynamic-conditional?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have that "serial" property. So Although you could do:

```
<b *ngIf="item.type == 'City'" >{{i+1}}.</b>
```

It's going to show the index, and not the "rank" which I think is a more correct term here.

instead, what you want appears to be more of calling a function and using that value:

```
 ngAfterViewInit(){
   this.lastRank = -1;
 }

  getNextRank(){   
    this.lastRank++;   
    return this.lastRank;
  }
```

ts:

```
<b *ngIf="item.type == 'City'"> {{getNextRank()}} </b>
```

And while this gets you closer, it has some fundamental problems in Angular. I wouldn't do it, even if it "makes sense" as someone newer to Angular.

Instead, the better route would be to use Hidden, but push the correct property onto the array:

```
import { AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit,  Component, OnInit,  VERSION } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  

 ngAfterViewInit(){
   let lastRank = 0;

   this.items.forEach(e => {
    if(e.type == "City"){
      lastRank++;
      e.cityRank = lastRank;
    }
   });
 }


  items: Place[] = [
    { type: "Country", title: "Armenia" },
    { type: "City", title: "Kapan" },
    { type: "City", title: "Goris" },
    { type: "City", title: "Hats’avan" },

    { type: "Country", title: "Angola" },
    { type: "City", title: "Catabola" },
    { type: "City", title: "Camacupa" },
    { type: "City", title: "Caluquembe" },

    { type: "Country", title: "Argentina" },
    { type: "City", title: "San Vicente" },
    { type: "City", title: "Santa Elena" },
    { type: "City", title: "Retiro" }
  ];
}

export class Place 
{
  type: string;
  title: string;
  cityRank?: number;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div>
  <p *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index;">
    <b [hidden]="item.type=='Country'"> {{item.cityRank}} </b>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.title}} &nbsp; ({{item.type}})
  </p>
</div>
```

[updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-serial-number-dynamic-conditional-snxdvi?file=src/app/app.component.html)

And result:

[image]

Comment: Any particular reason for adding the increment logic in  "ngAfterViewInit" event instead of "ngOnInit" event?

Comment: @VimalPatel none at all!

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:**

There are many ways to hide the serial numbers. Simplest is to add a `[hidden]` attribute to hide it when item type is country. Like below.

```
[hidden]="item.type=='Country'"
```

**Approach 2:**

If you want to keep the indentation same create a class name as `hide` like below and apply that class using `ngClass` if condition is true.

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

<b [ngClass]="{'hide':item.type=='Country'}">
```

Comment: no, the serial number is then skipping the serial of country

Comment: so you dont want to skip the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution
added a new getter

```
  get __items() {
    let i = 0;
    let newItem: { type: string; title: string; counter: number };
    return this.items.map(item => {
      if (item.type === "City") {
        i++;
      }
      newItem = Object.assign({}, item, { counter: i });
      return newItem;
    });
  }
```

and use it in template

```
<div>
    <p *ngFor="let item of __items">
        <b *ngIf="item.type==='City'">{{item.counter}}.</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.title}} &nbsp; ({{item.type}})
    </p>
</div>
```

[image]

stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-serial-number-dynamic-conditional-xsft3e

Comment: Catabola should start with 4. not 5.
it seems 4 is missing..

Comment: fixed it..please check

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ol` html tag and render only cities within the `li` tag.

```
<div>
    <ol style="list-style-type: decimal;">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
            <li *ngIf="item.type === 'City'; else country">
                {{ item.title }}
            </li>
            <ng-template #country>
                {{ item.title }}
            </ng-template>
        </ng-container>
    </ol>
</div>
```

See forked stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-serial-number-dynamic-conditional-esgwc3?file=src/app/app.component.html